# How do I draw the vector A B and C and find the position vectors of P, Q and R and show that these points are collinear?

Tags: calculus, vectors

A B and C have position vectors , a-b , 3a+2b and 4a-3b &
 P lies on AB where AP:AB =2:3 , Q lies on BC where BQ:BC= 3:4 and R lies on AC extended so that AC=CR

Where I am getting stuck is dividing the line AB into the ratio 2AP:3AB. 
My attempt was that AP is 2/5 of the line and 3AB is 3/5 of the line 
Also I tried dividing the line BC for the ratio 3BQ:4BC into 3/7 BQ and 4/7 BC 
When I try to join the points P Q and R ,they don't end up lying on the same line 
Please can someone explain where I am going wrong . 
Is there a method or formula used to divide the lines in a given ratio if not in fractions ?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: The construction of the points is incorrect. For instance if $\vec{P}$ is on the segment $AB$, this means that $\vec{P} = \vec{A} + \lambda (\vec{B}-\vec{A})$ for some constant $\lambda$. If in addition $AP:AB=2:3$ $P$ lies between them and this implies $\lambda=\frac{2}{3}$. As another hint, making a drawing of the problem will help you in finding the proper locations. Finally, is there anything that makes you believe that the points $P,Q,R$ should be on  a straight line?